# SignalR Page Refresh Makes Multiple Connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I want to show some live random data on client using SignalR.

> Problem Is whenever I refresh the page it creates one more connection
>   and shows multiple data.

Mostly I think my approach is wrong.

So what I have done.

Step 1: Installed SignalR Using Nuget `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR`

Step 2: Made changes in Startup.cs File as follows.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        app.MapSignalR(); //Added this line for SignalR
    }
}
```

Step 3: Created Hub Class. "ServerStatisticsHub.cs"

```
public class ServerStatisticsHub : Hub
{
    public void ServerParameter()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int p = 0;
        int m = 0;
        int s = 0;

        while(true) //May be this is the foolish thing I'm doing
        {
            p = r.Next(0, 100);
            m = r.Next(0, 100);
            s = r.Next(0, 100);
            Clients.All.broadcastServerStatistics("{\"processor\":" + p + ", \"memory\":" + m + ", \"storage\":" + s + "}");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

Step 4: Created an View in Home "ServerState.cshtml".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <title>TestSignalR</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="serverProcessor"></div>
    <div id="serverMemory"></div>
    <div id="serverStorage"></div>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js")"></script>    
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
            var serverStatistics = $.connection.serverStatisticsHub;

            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
            serverStatistics.client.broadcastServerStatistics = function (serverStat) {
                var serverStatistic = JSON.parse(serverStat);
                console.log(serverStatistic);

                $('#serverProcessor').html(serverStatistic.processor + "%");
                $('#serverMemory').html(serverStatistic.memory + "%");
                $('#serverStorage').html(serverStatistic.storage + "%");
            };

            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                serverStatistics.server.serverParameter();
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround to fix this issue.
I don't know how to describe it.

The following code change done in Hub Class file. "ServerStatisticsHub.cs"

```
Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).broadcastServerStatistics("{\"processor\":" + p + ", \"memory\":" + m + ", \"storage\":" + s + "}");
```

Changed

> Clients.All.

to

> Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).

Comment: I wouldn't really call it a workaround, this is actually a _possibly proper_ solution. Your problem was caused by the fact that you call the function which contains the infinite loop whenever a client connects. So Client 1 connects -> infinite loop launched. Client 2 connects -> infinite loop launched again. They run on different threads so launching it again does not kill the previous one. Since you don't exit from the loop by any means every new client causes a new infinite loop to be started each of which in turn broadcasts messages to every _other_ clients as well.

Comment: So is there any solution to close the infinite loop whenever page reloads?.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't launch an infinite loop for every new client in the first place. Why I said that what you've done could be a possible solution is because it really could be, in the case the messages don't need to be broadcasted to _all_ connected clients.